# Creating textbox dynamically

Tags: c#

I have created a text box and a button. When a value is entered and button is clicked, it should generate the same number of text boxes that I have entered in the text box field.

For example if I have entered a value 5 in the text box and clicked the button, then 5 text boxes should be generated automatically.

My question is how to align those text boxes vertically?

Comment: I think it is better if you change the title to "Align textboxes dynamically using c#". Because you have asked for that instead of how to create components dynamically.

Comment: One possibility would be to use [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to *layout* the new items.

Comment: You should add that as an answer.

Comment: How can this question possibly be answered without knowing the technology? WinForms, WPF, etc? And the title is wrong. Please edit the question and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a starting Y value, and you know the height of each dynamically generated textbox, then simple arithmetic will give you the value of Y for each textbox:

```
int y = 24;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Textbox tb = generateTextbox();
    tb.Top = y + i * tb.Height;
    addToForm(tb);
}
```

Something like this pseudocode should work.

*Edit*: This is for Windows Forms, which I assume you're using (at time of this writing you haven't said).

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try this it will surely help you

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Grab your text box value here; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Width = width value;
            tb.Height = hight value;
            tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
            tb.ID = "Common Name" + (i).ToString();
            tb.Text = Predefine Text;
            tb.Visible = true;

        }
```

Comment: His ultimate question was how to align the text boxes, not how to generate them. His title is misleading.

Comment: It is simple just add one more line in loop  tb.TextAlign = VerticalAlignment.Center;

Comment: I think - but might be wrong - that he's asking about the controls' positions on the form, not the text alignment.

Comment: Ya that's true let me find